# WPF Application Crashes when making HTTP request via Facebook's Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I wrote an application that gets my personal info from Facebook using the Graph API. When debugging the application in Visual Studio, everything runs fine. I created an installer using Advanced Installer and installed the program on my system. When I click a button that requires an Graph API request, the program stalls and crashes.

I was just able to debug using Visual Studio and got a FileNotFound exception saying, "Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook, Version=6.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken...' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Not sure where to go from here, but any helpful tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your setup package failed to deploy your app file or one of its dependencies. You should check into your installation folder for the deployed files and make sure all of them were successfully deployed/copied on local machine after installation.